# How to solve jQuery DatePicker Bug?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using jQuery DatePicker and it shows wrong date for November, 2009.

Is this a known bug? How can I fix it?

I get below answers from stack .

```
printDate.setUTCDate(printDate.getUTCDate() + 1);
```

to this

```
printDate.setDate(printDate.getDate() + 1);
```

I have follow above process in my code `printDate.setDate(printDate.getDate() + 1);` in file name `ui.datepicker.js`. But still showing the same issue. In my calender nov 04 showing two times. Can any one please help me?

Comment: What exactly is wrong date? What does it show, and what should it show?

Comment: I have not seen this issue, what you have mentioned. http://jsfiddle.net/a3Jfq/
which version are you using?

Comment: Hi Tks for your reply. I am using Jquery ui date picker. I am using version jQuery 1.2.6. I have download the Jquery ui date picker file form http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker. please check the screen shot for ur reference http://screencast.com/t/UFQ8pv1FdLD   I have change above process (printDate.setDate(printDate.getDate() + 1);) on ui.datepicker.js this file. Can you pls help me ..